# Desktop duplication: Rotating the frames to support portrait mode

Tags: visual-c++, directx, directx-11, direct3d, desktop-duplication

I'm using d3d11 (desktop duplication) to capture the screens and send them over the network on windows 8 and above Operating Systems. The problem is that the frames are flipped/rotated if the monitor is set in portrait mode and couldn't render properly.

After analyzing I came to know that I have had to handle the following rotation modes but I did get only limited resources related to this,

```
typedef enum DXGI_MODE_ROTATION { 
  DXGI_MODE_ROTATION_UNSPECIFIED  = 0,
  DXGI_MODE_ROTATION_IDENTITY     = 1,
  DXGI_MODE_ROTATION_ROTATE90     = 2,
  DXGI_MODE_ROTATION_ROTATE180    = 3,
  DXGI_MODE_ROTATION_ROTATE270    = 4
} DXGI_MODE_ROTATION;
```

After spending a lot of time going through the resources I had come across a code in webrtc that rotates the captured buffer using libyuv.

Here is the code I got from Webrtc for rotating the captured image buffer:

Reference : [desktop_frame_rotation.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/HEAD/modules/desktop_capture/desktop_frame_rotation.cc)

```
void RotateDesktopFrame(const DesktopFrame& source,
                        const DesktopRect& source_rect,
                        const Rotation& rotation,
                        const DesktopVector& target_offset,
                        DesktopFrame* target) {
  RTC_DCHECK(target);
  RTC_DCHECK(DesktopRect::MakeSize(source.size()).ContainsRect(source_rect));
  // The rectangle in |target|.
  const DesktopRect target_rect =
      RotateAndOffsetRect(source_rect, source.size(), rotation, target_offset);
  RTC_DCHECK(DesktopRect::MakeSize(target->size()).ContainsRect(target_rect));

  if (target_rect.is_empty()) {
    return;
  }

  int result = libyuv::ARGBRotate(
       source.GetFrameDataAtPos(source_rect.top_left()), source.stride(),
       target->GetFrameDataAtPos(target_rect.top_left()), target->stride(),
       source_rect.width(), source_rect.height(),
       ToLibyuvRotationMode(rotation));
  RTC_DCHECK_EQ(result, 0);
}

}
```

It's fine but libYuv doesn't have GPU support and it would be really slow to rotate the screens using CPU power.

Also I got a [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824276/direct3d11-flipping-id3d11texture2d) that discusses about frame rotations through directX itself but that too incomplete.

It would be really appreciable if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: Is this a problem you actually need to solve? LibYuv includes many CPU specific optimizations (some of them in assembly level code). It's basically just transposing sequences of bytes so I don't think it would be as slow as you think.  

I think copying the bytes to the GPU, rendering them out in a different orientation and then copying them back might actually take longer but 
I don't have any evidence for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Media Foundation [Video Processor MFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162913) can help with rotation while doing the work on GPU whenever possible. See [`IMFVideoProcessorControl::SetRotation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448074) method description specifically.

If Media Foundation sounds complicated (which it indeed is) but you are familiar with Direct3D 11 in general, you can use what Direct3D 11 instead: either by utilizing rotation [video processor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447655) or rendering the texture with respectively rotated quad.